# Comparing DateObjects with sub-second differences

Tags: date-and-time

How can I properly compare `DateObjects` with differences less than a second?

This

```
DateObject[{2018, 3, 1, 4, 15, 52}] <= DateObject[{2018, 3, 1, 4, 15, 52.1}]
```

gives

```
LessEqual::nordol: Thu 1 Mar 2018 04:15:52GMT+2. and Thu 1 Mar 2018 04:15:52GMT+2. 
cannot be compared because they are overlapping.
```

Although `IpnutForm` of the created `DateObject` correctly lists the fractions of the seconds, I think I would need something like `{y, m, d, h, m, s, ms}` as input for the `DateObject` (which is not working as it is)?

Edit: Using `AbsoluteTime` in front of the `DateObjects` is a workaround I'm aware of.

Comment: On Win10 and all V10.4, V11.2, V11.3 your code returns `True`.

Comment: Interesting, I'm running MacOS 10.13.2, Mathematica 11.1.1.0 .

Comment: Also returns `True` for Mathematica 11.3.0 on  Mac OS X 10.11.6

Comment: Works fine with both V11.0.1 and V11.3 on macOS 10.13.4.

Comment: I just upgraded to V11.3.0.0 and can confirm it is working now.